# don't close angular ui bootstrap dialog out side click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

When i click on the black background , the dialog get closed , but i didn't want it to get closed ..

[image]

Here is the code :

```
var disconnectedDialog = $dialog.dialog({       backdrop: 'static', keyboard:false });
```

What option i add in this that dialog doesn't get closed ..

Please tell what to do ...... 
Please tell what to do ......

Please tell what to do ......

Comment: @TyndieRock's answer worked for me. Why didn't you accept his answer or leave a comment indicating why it didn't work for you?

Answer (score 8):

It appears you have the correct option already set.  When you are setting up your modal there is an option called backdrop that allows you to either show or hide the backdrop.  However according to the documentation there is another option 'static':

> backdrop - controls presence of a backdrop. Allowed values: true
>   (default), false (no backdrop), 'static' - backdrop is present but
>   modal window is not closed when clicking outside of the modal window.

An example would be:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      backdrop: 'static',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });
```

I'm not sure what else is wrong the only suggestion may be to try the modal directive.  The Angular-UI team have removed dialog as of the current version.